# Extracting Filiform Areas using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

how can I extract `filiform areas` on the center of an image using MATLAB ?

Comment: Are they sharp (e.g. nice white on black) or blurred? Are they superimposed or clearly distinguishable?
Give some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A picture and some more details on the structures you want to extract would make it easier to answer.

You could get started using this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25157-blobsdemo

Comment: This is not really an answer. I cant yet seem to add comments to questions.

Comment: The image is `tr2.bmp` it's on the demo images of MATLAB.

Comment: @hash blue: That's because you have <50 reputation :)

Comment: @AZIRAR: Not sure what you mean by 'demo images of MATLAB'. This file does not appear to be part of the product. A google search returned nothing promising either.

@nico: right :) I should have looked at the extended FAQ first.

Comment: Take a look here : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009b\toolbox\images\imdemos

Comment: @AZIRAR: Any chance you could upload it somewhere? I don't use Matlab, but may be able to help with the problem in general.

Comment: @AZIRAR The image is not among the demo images in `.../imdemos` in my installations.